# unable to test AJAX ResponseText

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, responsetext

My PHP code responds to AJAX call with different strings, depending ... so I want to test the response, but I haven't been able to do it. I found that the responseText was of undefined type so tried type casting:

```
if (String(xmlhttp.responseText)=="OK")
{
    // do something
} else
{
    // display the responseText
    document.getElementById(spanID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Guess what gets displayed? OK. (Same without typecasting). Why?

Comment: You mean that the `else` block is run while the response is `OK`? Are there spaces in the response?

Comment: Try checking the string length of your response - it probably not the length of two.

Comment: have you tried to trim any whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

If there really isn't more than we're seeing here, your string must either have whitespace or other non printable characters in it.  Try trimming it before doing the comparison.

*Edit* Also try putting console logging in both your 'if' and 'else' blocks - maybe your method is being called multiple times unexpectedly and there is an odd race condition.

Comment: & others (thanks) -same output (apparently 'OK' substituted into document element) when using:
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     var trimmed = String(xmlhttp.responseText).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') ;
     if (trimmed=="OK")
     {
   // do something
  }
     else
     {
      document.getElementById(spanID).innerHTML=trimmed;
     }
    }
odd?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var text = xmlhttp.responseText.trim();//use trim()

if (text=="OK"){
    // do something
}else{
    // display the responseText
    document.getElementById(spanID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```